# Can constructorless classes have their methods called without instantiation?

Tags: c#

Can I avoid initializing this?

I have a simple factory with **no constructor**. I use it like this:

```
var slf = new GenericSelectListFactory();
vm.Works = slf.getWorkgsl(0);
vm.Cars = slf.getCargsl(0);
```

I can also use it like this:

```
vm.Cars = new GenericSelectListFactory().getCargsl(0);
```

Is there any way to use it without the new keyword?

```
vm.Cars = GenericSelectListFactory.getCargsl(0);
```

Comment: If you don't want/need an instance, why not make the method `static`?

Comment: It would also make sense to make the class `static`, if you only plan on it having static members.

Comment: Also note that there's a difference between "constructorless" classes and "stateless" classes. Only static classes truly have no constructor, non-static ones have an implicit constructor generated by the compiler.

Comment: @zneak - You can have a static constructor. ;)

Comment: From the MSDN article [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) `Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation. For more information, see Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide).`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the method of your class static.

```
class GenericSelectListFactory
{
   public static List<Cars> getCargsl()
   {
      // your logic here
   }

}
```

Comment: This allows the call to be made: `var cars = GenericSelectListFactory.getCargsl();`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

without "new" you should mark method as static

Answer (score 3):

A class without a constructor is assigned a default constructor by the compiler, mainly to eliminate the need for empty constructors:

> Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation.

If you want to access the methods without initializing the class, make the method(s) `static`. In doing this though, you should ensure that the methods are thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

you can make the functions static.